# Estado de ejecución de un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, xml

Actualmente tengo una aplicación en VB.NET que se encarga de insertar/actualizar una cantidad enorme de registro de "clientes"; se requiere un archivo de excel/dbf con los datos a procesar y convertirla en formato .xml para enviarlo a un procedimiento almacenado en mi bases de datos y aprovechar el rendimiento del lado del servidor. Esa manera ha sido una perfecta solución con un mínimo tiempo de 58seg.

Pero tengo que esperar ese tiempo (58seg) para presentar la respuesta al usuario sobre los datos procesados y me gustaria presentar el avance de los registros procesados por el procedimiento almacenado. (ademas de una barra de carga que al cliente le gustaria observar).

Me gustaria saber la manera que la aplicación muestre el estado de ejecución del procedimiento almacenado y elementos procesados para aplicarlo en una "barra de carga". muchas gracias por una guía que me ayude a realizar este requerimiento no funcional.

Comment: Hola, yo el otro día estuve viendo algo parecido, mi tiempo es superior al tuyo y al cliente no le molestaba esperar hasta que se haga la carga de los clientes por lo que usé este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZYAaScEsc0)  para hacer la ventana de carga, espero te sirva de guía para lo que necesitas hacer, saludos

Comment: wow, no habia pensado hacer la barra de carga de esa manera mientra espera la finalización del proceso. Gracias